# Rails 4 View Rendering Very Slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I've been developing my first Rails App and it has suddenly become very slow. I am not sure what has caused it. I had already added paperclip for management of images and just switched to using Dropbox (as opposed to local) storage just before it started going slow but I also made some unrelated view changes as well.

Now, I am relatively new to Rails and MVC Frameworks in general. So I do suspect it is something I am doing wrong due to ignorance and lack of experience. It's just that the same ignorance and lack of experience makes it difficult to diagnose the problem.

So, here is the output when running in development with "rails server" (though production on Heroku wasn't much faster).

```
    Started GET "/games/index" for 217.156.133.130 at 2014-05-16 09:31:10 -0400
    Started GET "/games/index" for 217.156.133.130 at 2014-05-16 09:31:10 -0400
    Processing by GamesController#index as HTML
    Processing by GamesController#index as HTML
      Game Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "games".* FROM "games" ORDER BY name ASC
      Game Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "games".* FROM "games" ORDER BY name ASC
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 9]]
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 9]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 9]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 9]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 5]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 5]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 5]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 5]]
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 7]]
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 7]]
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 7]]
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 7]]
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 12]]
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 12]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 12]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 12]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 2]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 2]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 2]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 2]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 10]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 10]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 10]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 10]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 23]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 23]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 23]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 23]]
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 18]]
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 18]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 18]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 18]]
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 3]]
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 3]]
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 3]]
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 3]]
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 13]]
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 13]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 13]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 13]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 24]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 24]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 24]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 24]]
   (1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 17]]
   (1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 17]]
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 17]]
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 17]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 4]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 4]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 4]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 4]]
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 8]]
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 8]]
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 8]]
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 8]]
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 19]]
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 19]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 19]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 19]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 15]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 15]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 15]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 15]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 16]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 16]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 16]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 16]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 20]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 20]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 20]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 20]]
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 21]]
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 21]]
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 21]]
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 21]]
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 22]]
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 22]]
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 22]]
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 22]]
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 1]]
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 1]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 1]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 1]]
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 6]]
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 6]]
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 6]]
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 6]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 11]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 11]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 11]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 11]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 14]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 14]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 14]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_games" ON "users"."id" = "user_games"."user_id" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" = $1  [["game_id", 14]]
  Rendered games/index.html.erb within layouts/application (77221.9ms)
  Rendered games/index.html.erb within layouts/application (77221.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 77227ms (Views: 77194.1ms | ActiveRecord: 31.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 77227ms (Views: 77194.1ms | ActiveRecord: 31.4ms)
```

As you can see the View is taking nearly a minute and 20 seconds to render, and database access isn't really an issue. Here is the view that this is rendering.

```
    <h1>All Games</h1>

<%= link_to "Add new", games_new_path %>

<% @games.each do |game| %>
  <div class="game">
    <div class="game_image">
      <% if game.image.exists? %>
        <%= image_tag game.image.url(:thumb) %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="game_info">
      <h2><%= link_to game.name, game %></h2><%= link_to "Edit", edit_game_path(game) %><br />
      <% if game.free %>
        This game is free.<br />
        <% if game.notes != "" %>
          N.B. <%= game.notes %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <%= game.users.size %> Players<br />
      <div class="user_list">
      <% game.users.each do |user| %>
        <div class="user_thumb">
          <% if user.avatar.exists? %>
            <%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar.url(:pinky)), user %>
          <% else %>
            <div class="alt_link">
              <%= link_to user.name, user %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_div"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My knowledge from just general programming suggests to me that the most costly part of this should be the fact that for each game I am looping through all of its users (users and games have a many-to-many relationship). However, each table in the database has only tens of records... there is hardly any data to process, so I don't believe it should really be quite *this* slow.

As a Rails novice, can anyone recommend to me some steps I can take to try and see what is causing this? I have googled around and I see that a lot of people have this problem but apparently there are many reasons it can happen because nothing I have found has solved my particular problem.

EDIT: After adding Eager Loading, Active Record is much quicker but View rendering is still extremely slow.

```
Started GET "/games/index" for 217.156.133.130 at 2014-05-16 10:07:07 -0400
Started GET "/games/index" for 217.156.133.130 at 2014-05-16 10:07:07 -0400
Processing by GamesController#index as HTML
Processing by GamesController#index as HTML
  Game Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "games".* FROM "games" ORDER BY name ASC
  Game Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "games".* FROM "games" ORDER BY name ASC
  UserGame Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "user_games".* FROM "user_games" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" IN (9, 5, 7, 12, 2, 10, 23, 18, 3, 13, 24, 17, 4, 8, 19, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 1, 6, 11, 14)
  UserGame Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "user_games".* FROM "user_games" WHERE "user_games"."game_id" IN (9, 5, 7, 12, 2, 10, 23, 18, 3, 13, 24, 17, 4, 8, 19, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 1, 6, 11, 14)
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (5, 6, 4, 1, 9, 8, 11)
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (5, 6, 4, 1, 9, 8, 11)
  Rendered games/index.html.erb within layouts/application (79191.5ms)
  Rendered games/index.html.erb within layouts/application (79191.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 79196ms (Views: 79191.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 79196ms (Views: 79191.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)
```

Comment: What is in your controller?  Looks like an N+1 queries issue.  You should try eager loading `@games = Game.includes(:users)` if you've not already done that

Comment: Ahh. This is new to me. Currently I have `@games = Game.all.order("name ASC")`

Comment: I think there are about 20-25 games and 15-20 users at the moment.

Comment: Ok so your current code gets all the games then each time you iterate over a game rails goes and gets the users for this game from the database.  So it is doing an extra query for each game.  By doing `Game.includes(:users)` you're telling rails you want all the users for these games so it will get all the games then it will get all the users who have a game_id in those games so just 2 queries.  [More info on rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)  Does that make sense?  I'm pretty rubbish with explanations

Comment: @Baloo I added Eager Loading, thanks. That will be very helpful for the future; it has improved ActiveRecord a lot but the view rendering is still very slow. You can see this in the Edit I just made to my original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `exists?` in Paperclip is very slow because it will either be checking the filesystem, or if you are using Amazon S3 it will make an http request, every time its called. Instead of using `exists?` you can use `game.image?` and `user.avatar?`. This will only check if a filename is stored in the database, instead of checking if the file actually exists. If you aren't worried about these images getting deleted outside the context of your Rails app it will be much faster.

Comment: I believe this was the problem. I originally added it because some of the images were inaccessible on the Heroku server for whatever reason. This is also why I moved to Dropbox. running without .exists? speeds things up a heck of a lot (down to around 1 second), but the page now crashes due to inaccessible images. I guess I will modify any existing objects where the image does not exist to use a default image to get around this. Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I would start by commenting out any of the ruby code within your ERB file, and try to pinpoint exactly what line is causing the render to slow to a crawl.  I've never used Paperclip but @abstractcoder's response could certainly be a cause.

Another option would be to use fragment caching, as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching).  It will allow you to cache parts of the views so that they are rendered from disk instead of processed on every request.  It's pretty slick in that you can cache certain parts of code, but it will still be smart enough to bust the cache if the model is updated.

But before you do any premature optimization, definitely look for the root cause first.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Threeve! abstractcoder's diagnosis does seem to be correct, but your suggestion of fragment caching will certainly come in handy once the app gets bigger. :)